# Is Phone-Charging Plant Product Even Possible?

Tags: energy, electricity, energy-conservation

[Bioo](http://www.bioo.tech), a new company making the [rounds](http://www.digitaltrends.com/home/bioo-charge-smartphone-from-plants/) [in](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/bioo-lite-arkyne-technologies-charge-phone_us_571e7213e4b01a5ebde2ea12) [the](http://gadgetsin.com/bioo-lite-plant-pot-charges-your-smartphone-with-electricity-from-plants-photosynthesis.htm) [press](http://betanews.com/2016/04/20/charge-your-phone-from-a-plant/), claims to produce "electricity from plants' photosynthesis."  Specifically, their website claims that a single potted plant with their integrated system provides "night and day electrical production," allowing for 2 to 3 "charges" of a cell phone per day ("Power: 5.0v, 1.0A") and "Exponential Electrical Production," whatever that means.  Their website and [IndieGoGo](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/bioo-charge-your-phone-with-the-power-of-a-plant) campaign provide no actual explanation of how this works.  They basically say, it's super simple, even you can understand it, here is how it works: the plant undergoes photosynthesis, and we turn the byproducts into energy!  That basically means and explains nothing.

I know that [James Franck studied synthetic photosynthesis](http://www.life.illinois.edu/govindjee/Part3/8_Rosenberg_On_Franck.pdf) in his later years, and others have investigated the endeavor since.  But actually synthesizing, tapping into, or otherwise seriously accruing energy via photosynthesis, synthetic or otherwise, and not counting methods involving the burning of organic materials (secondary or tertiary to the photosynthetic process), seems far from possible now.  So what is this plant probably doing, if anything?

I've heard of [similar](http://news.discovery.com/tech/alternative-power-sources/plant-lamp-draws-electricity-from-soil-151124.htm) systems, but nothing with any more coherent an explanation. Apparently solar panels can generate about [16W/square foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_panel#cite_note-4), which is a lot more than this plant thing claims to, so outside of the aesthetic is there even any point to a soil-based generator like this (presuming it is real and works?)?

Comment: This was also asked [on the skeptics stack exchange](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32647/can-one-generate-enough-electricity-from-a-plant-to-power-a-cellphone).

Comment: @CraigGidney is the modus operandi to close the question as a duplicate then, or to leave it open assuming the physics answers would bring a different perspective than the skeptics answers?

Comment: One can produce quite a bit of energy trough plants, but it requires a non-trivial number of bulls, which eat the plants and then produce manure (aka "shit"), which then can be dried into patties and burned in a conventional power plant. The process is known as "bullshitting" and it has a rather low efficiency.

Comment: @CuriousOne the process is very efficient for turning ignorance (of investors) into cash flow (flor company). But not so good at turning sunlight into electricity.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Generally the sites run independently, and so 'Duplicate' is only for within-the-same-site questions. I'd just add a self-answer pointing at the other site and quoting the most relevant part of the answer there (if it satisfied you). Same as if it wasn't a stack-exchange site.

Comment: On a more serious note... photosynthesis as performed by complex plants has a thermodynamic efficiency of around 0.1-1% (the reasons for that are physical... plants are green because they have to reflect 90% of the solar radiation to protect themselves from drying out, from UV damage etc.). Even so the molecules they use to photosynthesize break all the time and the plant has to spend a lot of energy on rebuilding the molecular apparatus. In essence, there is no competition to solar panels in terms of thermodynamic efficiency. Biology is so inferior that it's not even funny.

Comment: @Floris: I agree... but one can do that with solar panels and nano-particles, too. Nanosolar (RIP) has been extracting billions from investors as sophisticated as Google a decade ago. In comparison, this is small potatoes (pun!).

Comment: On another note: there is one serious physical technology step missing in the ultimate use of solar energy: it's a mechanism that can convert a photon into an electric potential difference without a charge-separation system with constant band-gap. The Schockley-Queisser limit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley%E2%80%93Queisser_limit) is a technological stepping stone for single junction and multi-junction designs, it's not a hard thermodynamics limit for solar cell efficiency. If we can find a system that sidesteps it, then 80% or even 90% efficient cells will become commonplace.

Comment: @CuriousOne wouldn't the generation of electrons with different energies lead to heating the moment they are collected on a common conductor?

Comment: Ok I wrote an answer summing up what appears to be the group consensus @CraigGidney

Comment: @Floris: That is the difficulty with the Schockley-Queisser limit... we need a mechanism that "sorts" different charge carrier energies/momenta and "adds" them instead of applying them in parallel. The straight forward solution is by using multi-junction cells which are electrically in series, blue on top, then green, red and IR absorbing junctions on the bottom, but that's expensive to manufacture. If one could find a nano-material that can use quantum mechanics to coherently transfer individual energies before thermalizing them on the lattice, that would solve the problem. No luck, so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question appears to be a [pseudo-duplicate](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32647/can-one-generate-enough-electricity-from-a-plant-to-power-a-cellphone) on the Skeptics exchange, as pointed out by @CraigGidney.  The highlights of the comments here and answer there appear to be that:

1) Yes, [one could](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell) potentially accrue some electricity from soil.

2) [No, it would not (ever) be sufficient to charge an iPhone](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/32649/30003), let alone 3 times.

3) In the comments here, "there is no competition to solar panels in terms of thermodynamic efficiency" (@CuriousOne).

Searching the web, we skeptics find [multiple](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2015/08/how-can-you-generate-electricity-from-living-plants/) claims from people claiming they can "harvest electrons" "non invasively" from plants.  When asked how this is done, the overwhelming answer appears to be "technology."  As in, "how did you fly to Mars over the weekend?"  "Technology."  "Cool!"

As an aside, there appears to be some [legitimate science](http://cleantechnica.com/2013/05/11/harvesting-electricity-from-plants-plant-based-energy-generation/) at work in the get-energy-from-plants-game.  But it is very much in research-stage, and very much invasive, and very much not being funded by IndieGoGo.

**TL;DR**: The product is probably a lie.

Comment: I would agree with this overall assessment. One could add one additional rule: "If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is."